# Origen de la expresión "¡largo!" para obligar a alguien a retirarse

Tags: etimología, interjecciones

Pues, eso, que me parece curioso gritar ¡*largo*! mientras se apunta a la puerta con el dedo y se mira al perro con odio.

En el DRAE no aparece entre las definiciones de [largo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MwNMwao), sino más abajo entre las frases y locuciones de uso frecuente:

> **largo**
>
> **1.** interj. U. para mandar a una o más personas que se vayan inmediatamente.

Y en la entrada del diccionario de "largar" se nos informa que proviene "*de largo*". ¿Alguien sabe cuál es la relación entre la *longitud* de algo (su *largo*) y la acción obligatoria de retirarse de un lugar?

Comment: En España decimos _largarse_ a _irse_. Veo en la RAE que [_largar_](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MwDog5u) tiene la acepción marítima _Dicho de una nave: Hacerse a la mar, o apartarse de tierra o de otra embarcación_. ¿Podría ser _largo_ una simplificación de _lárgate_ -> _quiero que te largues_ -> _te quiero largo de aquí_ -> te quiero lejos de aquí?

Comment: Toda la familia de palabras que incluye a *largo* tiene significados relacionados con "poner distancia" o "soltar", aunque *largar* también incluye la idea de "desplegar". El étimo latino es *largum* "abundante".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En 1734, el diccionario de Autoridades recogía la acepción *largar las velas* como "hacerse a la mar". En 1803 añadía *largarse* como:

> Hacerse la nave á la mar, ó apartarse de tierra, ó de otra embarcación.

Esa acepción de "apartarse de algo" es la que debió prevalecer y se amplió hasta significar "apartarse de otra persona". De hecho, en 1822 ya significaba también:

> Irse ó ausentarse con presteza una persona.

Así, en textos se pueden encontrar ejemplos como el siguiente (negritas mías en todos los ejemplos):

> *—Pos que los muchachos han cogido de trompo de ñiques al pobre negro, y yo se la azvertí a usté cuando me concerté, que yo traiba al negro; y él es muy noble y no se mete con naide, ni nada les está comiendo ni rasgando pa que se lo jarten; y hora mismo **me largo de aquí**, que lo qu'es comida a mí ni a mis hijos nos ha de faltar, primero Dios y mi sudor de mi frente, decía ña Sunción hecha un mar de lágrimas, pasándose el índice tendido por la rugosa frente y haciéndolo chasquear como látigo.*
>
> Magón (Manuel González Zeledón), "Sin cocinera [La propia y otros cuentos]", 1896 (Costa Rica).

De unos cuantos años antes es el siguiente ejemplo:

> *—Pues entonces **largaos de aquí** tú y ese miserable gazmoño al instante —replicó Saldaña.*
>
> José de Espronceda, "Sancho Saldaña o El Castellano de Cuéllar", 1834 (España).

Lo curioso es como ese "largaos de aquí" se convirtió en "largo de aquí", usando la primera persona de presente de indicativo, como si fuera la expresión que deseas oír de boca de aquel al que quieres largar:

> *—Pues ahora retírate, y cuidado con el piquito.
>
>   —Hagan ustedes cuenta que yo soy un muerto, y que a nadie le hablaré de este negocio; ¿pero qué le digo a mi cuñado?
>
>   —Nada más, sino que nos has entregado ese dinero.
>
>   —Pero... ¿y el niño?
>
>   —¡Silencio, y **largo de aquí**!*
>
> Julián Zugasti y Sáenz, "El Bandolerismo. Estudio social y memorias históricas", 1876 - 1880 (España).

Todos los ejemplos de "largo de aquí" y similares son del siglo XIX en adelante. El último paso es simplemente reducir la expresión "largo de aquí" a simplemente "largo", dado que esa forma verbal ya indica el deseo de perder de vista a tu interlocutor:

> *El chico estiró el cuello para ver qué era, y el Padre dijo: "**¡Largo!** Idos de aquí y dejadme en paz."*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "Miau", 1888 (España).

Answer (score 1):

En contexto de ubicación, lo largo esta lejos. Aquella longitud no es el juego de lineas verticales del mapa, sino la distancia en si.

Un sentido de *alargar* en el DRAE es: Ir a un sitio algo más lejano del que antes se pensó. Semejantemente, *largar* tiene: Dicho de una persona: Irse o ausentarse con presteza o disimulo.

Los sinónimos del *largo*, *largo de ahí, o de aquí* aclaran que la longitud se extiende desde el actual sitio del hablador.

Me queda claro que *¡largo!* es análogo al decir *¡lárgate!*.